# Unable to import font into WPF application

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to add a custom font to my application, but I'm getting an error:

```
An object of the type "System.Windows.Style" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Windows.Media.FontFamily".
```

From the error, I'm guessing that it means, the font wasn't imported, but I'm not sure why it wasn't.
Here's the code in the `MainWindow.xaml` file:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Raleway">
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="fonts/#Raleway"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

```
<TextBlock Text="text" 
          FontWeight="Light"
          FontFamily="{StaticResource Raleway}"
          FontSize="22"
          Foreground="White"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          />
```

This is my directory:

[image: This is my directory]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following markup shows how to reference the application's font resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <FontFamily x:Key="Raleway">./fonts/#Raleway</FontFamily>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="text" 
          FontWeight="Light"
          FontFamily="{StaticResource Raleway}"
          FontSize="22"
          Foreground="White"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          />
```

When you add fonts as resources to your application, make sure you are setting the `<Resource>` element, and not the `<EmbeddedResource>` element in your application's project file. The `<EmbeddedResource>` element for the build action is not supported.

It is possible to package fonts with WPF application. The detailed information is here: [Packaging Fonts with Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/packaging-fonts-with-applications?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Thanks that worked. Can I ask how you found that syntax? `<FontFamily x:Key="Raleway">./fonts/#Raleway</FontFamily>`, when I was searching for this all I found was my original syntax which didn't work

Comment: @COOKIE: I used this in my application and found in the Microsoft documentation. :)

Comment: @COOKIE: In additional the `FontFamily` property of the `TextBlock` control has 'System.Windows.Media.FontFamily' type, not the `System.Windows.Style`. That exactly that error message says. Therefore, it should be used as noted above.